GitHub Actions for Automatic Cypress Testing Not Working
I'm currently trying to create a GitHub action where I run a Cypress test on PR changes on every PR open/reopen/update, when the PR have by target the staging branch
This is my yaml:
name: Run Cypress Tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - staging
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

jobs:
  cypress:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          yarn install
          yarn serve --port 3000

      - name: Run Cypress tests
        run: |
          npx cypress run --headless

      - name: Post comment if Cypress fails
        if: failure()
        run: |
          PR_URL=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
                        "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls" | jq -r '.[0].url')
          
          COMMENT="The Cypress tests failed. Please fix the issues before merging."
          curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
          -d "{\"body\": \"$COMMENT\"}" \
          "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/issues/comments"
          
          # Make GitHub request changes if Cypress fails
          curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
          -d "{\"event\": \"REQUEST_CHANGES\", \"body\": \"Cypress tests have failed. Please fix the issues.\"}" \
          "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls/${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}/reviews"

This is my repo package.json:
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "1.1.2",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=6.0.0 <9.0.0",
    "node": ">=14.0.0 <17.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "deploy": "aws --profile vue-deployer --region us-east-1 s3 sync ./dist s3://pichau-erp-front --delete"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "loader-utils": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "minimist": "^1.2.7",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.10.6",
    "v-mask": "^2.3.0",
    "v-money": "^0.8.1",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.15",
    "vue": "^2.7.3",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-jwt-decode": "^0.1.0",
    "vue-notification": "^1.3.20",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-simple-alert": "^1.1.1",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.7.1",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2",
    "webstomp-client": "^1.2.6",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "xml-js": "^1.6.11",
    "yarn": "^1.22.22"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "cypress": "^13.16.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "2.11.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.9.2"
  }
}

So as can you see, I use Vue 2, Node 16 and compatible versions of Cypress. But I created 2 PRs to staging branch and nothing happened, as you can see in the image
No Cypress Runs
How can I fix it? It is my first time creating an action and didn't found answers that solve my problem ?
I would like the test to run when creating the PR

my approach would be that you delete the types: [opened, synchronize, reopened] line
"... if no activity types are specified, the workflow runs when a pull request is opened or reopened or when the head branch of the pull request is updated." ~ from github actions website
Looking like:
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - staging


That didn't work :/ Opened PRs on the Repo and nothing happened yet

have you pushed it on main once?
Cause github is using the git actions from the main branch
